# Iterating through generic List of Object type

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist

I am trying to get values from a  object type generic List. And I want to put some condition on value of one attribute of that class.
For example I have Bean class User

```
class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String companyName;
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

I have stored three records of this in table. like 
 (FIRST_NAME , LAST_NAME , COMPANY_NAME)
 (John,Woods,Persistent) (Bill,Gates,Microsoft) (Steve,Jobs,Apple)

And when I am getting these records from table it's in a list like this

```
List<T> list = query.getResultList();
```

Now I want to check if any user has lastName = Jobs then change the value of Company to Google.

Someone please tell me how should I do this.

Comment: how is T defined on method level or class level? if not why can't you directly assign it to `List<User>`?

Comment: I have not assigned it as User because sometimes it can be of different class. The method in which I get the list of records is generic that means this method does the same thing for some other table also (or u can say class). So sometimes T can be other class also. but whenever that method gets called with T as User it should work as per the requirement.

Answer (score 6):

In the general case you can do this:

```
for(T item : list) { 
    if(item instanceof User && "Jobs".equals(((User)item).getLastName())) { 
         // Change company to google.
    }
}
```

Comment: List<T> list = query.getResultList(); The method in which this code is a Generic method . Means that method does the same thing for some other tables (or we can say class) also . For that reason I kept it as generic.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make a generic method do different things based on the type of `T`.

In a `List<T>`, there are no limitations on what type `T` can be, so all that it's known is that it's an object of some kind and you can only call methods that work on any object (i.e. methods defined in the `Object` class).  Basically, a variable of type `T` is effectively a variable of type `Object` at runtime.

You can use `instanceof` and casts to check whether the object is of a particular type:

```
for (T item : list) {
    if (item instanceof User) {
        User user = (User) item;
        // ...
    }
}
```

But this isn't really related to generics; you're not looking at the type of `T`, just the type of each individual object in the list.

Answer (score -2):

```
for(T element : list){
    if((element instanceof User) && (element.getLastName().equals("Jobs")))
        element.setCompany("Google");
}
```

And you will need setters and getters, since those fields are private.

Comment: Type T doesn't have a .getLastName() method

Comment: Which is why I said he needs setters and getters. lastName and company are private

Comment: The getters and setters are kinda implied here.  If I have a private field called foo and a comment that says // getters and setters, then I think it's OK to assume the existence of a .getFoo() method.  But you can only assume that on my type.  Not on generic type T

Comment: And can you assume that the fields are public on a generic type T?

Comment: sometime T can be of different type also ( not User only). But whenever it's User type it should put that validation.

Comment: Right FrobberOfBits. I have mentioned getters and setters in the code there.